# Signalr GlobalHost.Configuration.DisconnectTimeout doesn't change

Tags: c#, signalr, owin, self-hosting

In signalr documentation, the DisconnectTimeout is 30s by default.

But I tried to change it, but the value of DictonnectTimeout still always 30s.

```
class Startup
{

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Wait a maximum of 30 seconds after a transport connection is lost
        // before raising the Disconnected event to terminate the SignalR connection.
        GlobalHost.Configuration.DisconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);


        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.MapSignalR("/signalr", new HubConfiguration() { EnableDetailedErrors = true });

    }
}
```

I tested it, by closing the connection for a client, and the signalr server did 30s to terminate this connection.

So, my configuration didn't work :

```
// Wait a maximum of 30 seconds after a transport connection is lost
// before raising the Disconnected event to terminate the SignalR connection.
GlobalHost.Configuration.DisconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
```

Why ? I missed something ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone using Ninject or some other dependency injection framework, you must add the following lines before setting `DisconnectTimeout`:

```
var resolver = new NinjectSignalRDependencyResolver(kernel);
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = resolver;
```

where kernel is IKernel from Ninject. You likely already have the first line; the second line is the key.

Refer to [SignalR change DisconnectTimeout when using custom resolver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25724067/8792111)

Answer (score 0):

Try by calling it in the **Application_Start()** method of the Global.asax instead of the OWIN Startup file.

Comment: What if there is no Global.asax?